# How do add dynamic formControl inside FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

Here is what i have created in static way . I am using Angular 4.

```
   this.contactForm = this.fb.group({

  firstname: ['', Validators.required],
  lastname: ['', Validators.required],
  zipCode: ['', Validators.required],
  hobbies: this.fb.group({
    hobbies0: ['', Validators.required],
    hobbies1: ['', Validators.required],
    hobbies2: ['', Validators.required],
    hobbies3: ['', Validators.required],
    hobbies4: ['', Validators.required],
    hobbies5: ['', Validators.required]
  }),// want to create these controls using for loop.


})
```

And in HTML

```
 <form [formGroup]="contactForm " autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
         <input type="text" formControlName="firstname">
         <input type="text" formControlName="lastname">
         <input type="text" formControlName="zipCode">
         <div formGroupName="hobbies">
            <input type="text" formControlName="hobbies0">
            <input type="text" formControlName="hobbies1">
            <input type="text" formControlName="hobbies2">
            <input type="text" formControlName="hobbies3">
            <input type="text" formControlName="hobbies4">
            <input type="text" formControlName="hobbies5">
         </div>//want to iterate through ngFor
 </form>
```

So , i just came to know a way to create such things in dynamic way , by using `*ngFor` in html and also in typescript to create dynamic `controls`.

Comment: Seems like a use case for FormArray

Answer (score 0):

For example you can do something like this:

**component.ts**

```js
  public hobbiesArr = ['hobbies0', 'hobbies1', 'hobbies2', 'hobbies3', 'hobbies4'];

  ngOnInit() {
    const hobbiesGroup = {}
    this.hobbiesArr.forEach(hobby => {
      hobbiesGroup[hobby] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    })

    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: ['', Validators.required],
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],
      zipCode: ['', Validators.required],
      hobbies: new FormGroup(hobbiesGroup)
    })

  }
```

**component.html**

```js
     <form [formGroup]="contactForm" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" formControlName="firstname">
      <input type="text" placeholder="lastname" formControlName="lastname">
      <input type="text" placeholder="zipCode" formControlName="zipCode">

      <div formGroupName="hobbies">
        <input *ngFor="let hobby of hobbiesArr" [placeholder]="hobby" type="text" [formControlName]="hobby">
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      
     </form>
```

Comment: getting error `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("`

Comment: Have you imported `ReactiveFormsModule`?

Comment: `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: `import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Problem remains same in life.

Comment: Is `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `imports`? Here I created a small stackblitz project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eeyqzj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts